# Progressbar doesn't appear where it should be, with hover

Tags: html, css, hover, less, mixins

I'm working on a simple progressbar with LESS (I started a while ago).

```
[Codepen] http://codepen.io/mustafoski/pen/ybbVvJ
```

I'm not really sure what the issue is, however if you hover over the empty bar or the h2, you'll see that the bar is filling up. The issue you can see, is the bar is on top of the placeholder.

It should look like this: http://codepen.io/mustafoski/pen/VbpBEe
(I don't get it, why can I post this url without problems)

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you.

BR
Alim

Comment: You can add a link to your pen. It won't embed, but people will be able to visit it and that removes the friction of asking people to recreate it.

Comment: Every time when I put the codepen link in, this msg apperas: 

Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Thats why I used the code button.

Comment: This is a link to his Pen: http://codepen.io/mustafoski/pen/ybbVvJ/?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

After trying for a while, I figured it out. The code was alright only one class was missing at the hover part.

If you gonna look at my pen you will see this:

Old:

```
.bar(@widthInPercent)
{
  position:relative;
  content:"";
  width:0px;
  height:35px;
  background-color: @green;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-left:0px;
  margin:0px !important;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

  &:hover
  {
    width:@widthInPercent;
  }
}
```

New:

```
.bar(@widthInPercent)
{
  position:relative;
  content:"";
  width:0px;
  height:35px;
  background-color: @green;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-left:0px;
  margin:0px !important;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

  &:hover .bar /*This Class was missing*/
  {
    width:@widthInPercent;
  }
}
```

Thx for every one :)